# Shape error when using CRF for binary segmentation in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to apply a CRF layer to my network for binary segmentation, but it is resulting in an error `ValueError: Shapes (?, 1, 1) and (?, 336, 1) are not compatible`.

I want to output a tensor with the shape `(batch_size, 224, 336, 1)`.  Based on the error, the img_height appears to have been lost once the CRF was introduced.

Below is some sample code describing the model.  Without the CRF at the end it works well.

```
import keras
from keras.layers import UpSampling2D, Conv2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF

img_width, img_height = 336, 224
kernel_size = 7

input=keras.engine.topology.Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3))

e=Conv2D(32,(kernel_size,kernel_size),padding='same')(input)
e1=Activation('relu')(e)
e=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(e1)

e=Conv2D(64,(kernel_size,kernel_size),padding='same')(e)
e2=Activation('relu')(e)
e=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(e2)

#Decoder layers
d=UpSampling2D()(e)
d=Conv2D(64,(kernel_size,kernel_size),padding='same')(d)
d=Activation('relu')(d)

d=UpSampling2D()(d)
d=Conv2D(32,(kernel_size,kernel_size),padding='same')(d)
d=Activation('relu')(d)

d=Conv2D(1,(1,1),padding='valid')(d)
d=Activation('sigmoid')(d)

out=CRF(1, sparse_target=True)(d) 

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input, outputs=out)
```

What is the correct way to add the CRF to my segmentation network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that keras_contrib.layers.CRF is meant only for sequential data, not spatial data.  For using spatial data, the [densecrf library](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/pydensecrf/tree/94d1cddab277e6e93812dfe7daca7d4693560758) works.  It appears that it cannot be used during training, only for post-processing.  I used a tutorial to implement this, which can be found here: http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/18/image-segmentation-with-tensorflow-using-cnns-and-conditional-random-fields/